# Why is "crowdness" not a proper English word?

Tags: word-usage

Crowdedness is the state of being crowded. So why is "sadness" correct but "sadedness" not correct?

Comment: ...Because it isn't. More fundamentally, because a language defaults to not having a word unless someone specifically starts using that word. So, while it may be entirely valid to add such a word to the language (English has new words added all the time), no one's added it, so it isn't in the language. Every word started out as a non-word. That's how language works. Your question is a bit like asking "why haven't I been hit by a bus, given that people get hit by buses all the time?".

Answer (score 2):

1. Because *crowd* is a noun, not an adjective.
2. Because **saded* does not exist.

Comment: I vaguely recall that "saded" appears in a Simon & Garfunkel song

Comment: @Hot Licks: I must have heard every song S&G recorded, at least dozens if not hundreds of times. And pored over the written lyrics, back in the days when they were usually printed on the LP sleeves we used to roll joints on. But I never noticed anything like that.

Comment: ...on the other hand, [here's a case](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dwdYVrSbupcC&pg=PA175&dq=%22crowd+to+create+crowdness%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2FMVVfrPA-Te7AaKuYCgDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22crowd%20to%20create%20crowdness%E2%80%9D&f=false) where a competent writer has deliberately used ***crowdness*** (as distinct from ***crowdedness***) to reference *the quality of being a crowd* - apparently, focusing on how this affects crowd *behaviour*, rather than the "packing density" of people within the crowd.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - OK, I was thinking it was in "A Simple Desultory Philippic", but apparently not.

Comment: 3. Because English is a cruel and fickle mistress that don't owe nobody nothin', and consistency least of all.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Haha I remember [*that*](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/paulsimon/asimpledesultoryphilippic.html) one! Half-a-dozen of us (stoned Brits, having used the sleeve in the traditional manner) sitting around wondering who were all those "verbified" famous Americans (at least we *did* know both Dylans! :). I don't recall if any of us knew what a ***philippic*** meant at the time, but quite possibly ***I*** didn't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers and Hot Licks - though my acquaintance with cannabis is strictly medicinal and limited, the LP cover thing was never a good idea, because 1) "active ingredients" adhere to the album covers with a resulting loss of efficacy, and 2) the covers get tainted or tinted by The Medicine, and those covers are now worth gazillions of dollars (to say nothing of obscuring lyrical content). Dudes, why do you think Americans invented the Frisbee?

Comment: @HotLicks: I think what you heard was the verbing of Barry Sadler into the line "I've been Lou Adlered, Barry Sadlered." Sadlered, not saded.

Comment: @Robusto -- Possibly, but I could have sworn I heard something like "Marat/Saded" either in that song or a similar one.

Comment: @Robusto: It is undoubtedly a [mondegreen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen) deceiving you. But I remember the lyrics to songs, and I never heard anything like you say in that one. [Here are the lyrics](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/simongarfunkel/asimpledesultoryphilippicorhowiwasrobertmcnamaradintosubmission.html) if you don't believe me.